# How do we remove "search" segment from the url using $location?

Tags: angularjs

I have a three check boxes on the page and would like to pass the options checked in url. To do this I used $location.search("key":"value"), which works fine when user checks it. But when they uncheck and post a form back, I want to remove the ones that are false. So initially I might have `/myapp/search?id=123&opt1&opt2` when both options are checked. But when opt2 gets unchecked I am unable to transform url to `/myapp/search?id=123&opt1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call it with **null**

```
$location.search('opt2', null);
```

See the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#methods_search)

Comment: In addition to setting  it null one has to set the reloadOnSearch parameter on the route definition to false.